# How to add n elements in a list, where n is each item in another list?

Tags: python

I have the following three lists:

```
numlist = [0,4,0,4,0,4,0,0,4,0,4]
upperlist = ['EF','FA','FE','FY','IF','OF']
lenwords = [2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Where each item in `lenwords` represents the number of characters for each word in `upperlist`.

I want to add consecutive numbers in `numlist` n times, where n is equal to n in lenwords, so that the resulting list would look like this:

```
sumlist = [4,4,4,4,4,4]
```

The objective is to the zip `upperlist` and `sumlist` into a list of tuples, which would look something like this:

```
ziplist = [(4,'EF'), (4,'FA'), (4,'FE'), (4,'FY'), (4,'IF'), (4,'OF')]
```

I know how to zip both lists, I'm just getting stuck in how to access n in `lenwords` to add i + i+1 in `numlist`.

Comment: Would u please explain how `sumlist = [4,4,4,4,4,4]`?

Comment: sumlist would be the sum of consecutive numbers in numlist n times, where n is equal to n in lenwords.

Comment: When generating the sums, does each sum start at the beginning of `numlist`?  Or does it start where the previous sum ended?  The numbers in the example don't show the distinction, although since there are only 11, presumably there must be some overlap.

Comment: What does `i` represent?

Comment: @Juliana I don't understand that description. Aren't all the numbers "consecutive" since they're in the same list? Or do you mean numbers that are are non-decreasing, i.e. `[(0,4), (0,4), (0,4), (0,0,4), (0,4)]`? And what do you mean by "n times"? Is that not multiplication? To me that makes it sound like the end result should be `[8,8,8,8,8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of your progress

```
numlist = [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4]
upperlist = ['EF', 'FA', 'FE', 'FY', 'IF', 'OF']
lenwords = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

values = []
count = 0
for n in lenwords:
    values.append(sum(numlist[count:count + n]))
    count += n
print(values)
# [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

result = list(zip(values, upperlist))
print(result)
# [(4, 'EF'), (4, 'FA'), (4, 'FE'), (4, 'FY'), (4, 'IF'), (4, 'OF')]
```

Comment: Wait... that's not OP's data, `numlist` is different. Although I don't understand OP's description, so maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @wjandrea.  I believe the consecutive `..., 0, 0...` in the OPs post was a typo. it was supposed to be alternating `0, 4,` in it's entirety

Answer (score 0):

With numpy:

```
import numpy as np

numlist = [0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4]
upperlist = ['EF','FA','FE','FY','IF','OF']
lenwords = [2,2,2,2,2,2]

x = np.r_[0, lenwords[:-1]].cumsum()
list(zip(np.add.reduceat(numlist, x), upperlist))
```

It gives:

```
[(4, 'EF'), (4, 'FA'), (4, 'FE'), (4, 'FY'), (4, 'IF'), (4, 'OF')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the `lenwords` and generate the consecutive sum.

```
numlist = [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4]
upperlist = ['EF', 'FA', 'FE', 'FY', 'IF', 'OF']
lenwords = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]


def consecutiveSum(data):
    [index, n] = data
    return sum(numlist[index:index+n])


sumList = map(consecutiveSum, enumerate(lenwords))

print(sumList)  # [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Are you still using Python 2? In Python 3, `map()` creates a `map` object. To make it a list, `list(map(...))`

Comment: If the result doesn't have to be mutable I would suggest using a tuple. Furthermore, in this case, the brackets in the list unpacking is redundant.